# Intersecting co-cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of type $(m_1,\dotsc,m_r)$; that is, essentially, $G=\mathbb Z_{m_1}\oplus\dotsb\oplus\mathbb Z_{m_r}$ with integer $1<m_1\mid m_2\mid\dotsb\mid m_r$. Dropping for each $i\in[1,r]$ the $i$th direct summand, we get a system of $r$ co-cyclic subgroups of $G$ the intersection of which is the zero subgroup. Can one find fewer than $r$ co-cyclic subgroups of $G$ with zero intersection? What is the smallest $k=k(m_1,\dotsc,m_r)$ for which co-cyclic subgroups $H_1,\dotsc,H_k<G$ with $H_1\cap\dotsb\cap H_k=\{0\}$ exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you need at least $r$ such subgroups.

Let $d(G)$ be the smallest size of a generating set of a group $G$. Since the $G$ in the question has an elementary abelian quotient of order $p^r$, where $p$ is a prime dividing $m_1$, we have $d(G)=r$.

For a cocyclic subgroup $H_1$ of $G$, we have $d(G) \le d(H_1) + d(G/H_1) \le d(H_1) + 1$, so $d(H_1) \ge d(G)-1 = r-1$.

Then since $H_2 \cap H_1$ is cocyclic in $H_1$, we get $d(H_2 \cap H_1) \ge d(H_1) - 1$, and by induction $d(H_1 \cap \ldots \cap H_k) \ge r-k$.

Comment: I certainly agree with paragraphs 2 and 3, but could you expand on paragraph 4? Why is $H_2\cap H_1$ co-cyclic in $H_1$? (Hopefully, this will also explain why is $H_3\cap H_2\cap H_1$ co-cyclic in $H_2\cap H_1$ etc.)

Comment: That's one of the isomorphism theorems: $H_1/H_1 \cap H_2 \cong H_1H_2/H_2 \le G/H_2$.